# how to check if the device is being accessed remotely in android using Java ? or javascript for cordova?

Tags: javascript, java, cordova-plugins, remote-access, screensharing

I have an android app in which I just wanna check if the device is being operated remotely or not? such as via TeamViewer or any desk app or even if any screen sharing is ongoing
This is because I don't want someone to use my application remotely for security concerns.

I checked over the internet but couldn't find any solutions. 
Any help would be good.
Thanks.

Comment: If you have application with username/password Login Form. Only you can access right unless you shared ur credentials to others.

Comment: yes, but people can take access after login. @SureshKumarAriyaI just don't want users of my app to fall for any kind of frauds.

Comment: Is your application a web application or a native app ?

Comment: it's a Cordova app @SoumenMukherjee

Comment: Is it cordova with angular or cordova with angularjs? These tags typically don't go together since they refer to two very different versions of the technology.

Comment: well, either of the solutions will work for me. @OneLunchMan but still i have edited the tags

Comment: @MSD curious if you ever find the solution?

Comment: @Kazuki nope...